# How to Validate and Update an embedded object in a document of a mongoDB Collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

How can I update the values of an embedded object in a mongoDB document?

{{service.id}} and {{service.username}} show the correct values in the table template, but I am not sure how to call them in the `saveItem()` function.  When I try `service.id`, `service.$.id`, and `service.[0].id`, I get `Error: Unexpected token .`.  When I try `"service.id"`, the form submits and nothing happens, when I try `"service.[0].id"`, the form gets stuck on edit and nothing happens, and when I try `"service.$.id"`, I get an error saying the $ field cannot be updated.

Should I have something else in my javascript code? Or am I doing something wrong when defining the schema (i.e. don't need the dollar signs).

Thanks !

Here is my code:

```js
var Schemas = {};

Items = new Meteor.Collection('items');

Schemas.Items = new SimpleSchema({
  _id: {
    type: String,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    label: "Item Name",
    min: 1
  },
  "service.$": {
    type: [Object]
  },
  "service.$.id": {
    type: Number
  },
  "service.$.username": {
    type: String
  }

});

Items.attachSchema(Schemas.Items);



var saveItem = function() {
  var editItem = {
    _id: $('#editId').val(),
    name: $('#editName').val(),
    "service.$.id": $('#editServiceId').val(), //not working
    "service.$.username": $('#editServiceUsername').val() //not working
  }
 
  Items.update(Session.get('editItemId'), {$set: editItem}, {validationContext: 'updateForm'}, function(error, result) {
    if(!error){
      Session.set('editItemId', null);
    }
  });

}

Template._editItemsItem.helpers({
  editing: function() {
   return Session.equals("editItemId", this._id);
  }

});

Template._editItemsItem.events({
  'click .editItem': function() {
    Items.simpleSchema().namedContext('updateForm').resetValidation();
    Items.simpleSchema().namedContext('insertForm').resetValidation();
    Session.set("editItemId", this._id);
  },
  'click .cancelItemEdit': function() {
    Items.simpleSchema().namedContext('updateForm').resetValidation();
    Items.simpleSchema().namedContext('insertForm').resetValidation();
    Session.set("editItemId", null);
  },
  'click .saveItem': function() {
    saveTeam();
  },
  'keypress input': function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
      saveItem();
    }
    else if(e.keyCode === 27){
      Items.simpleSchema().namedContext('updateForm').resetValidation();
      Items.simpleSchema().namedContext('insertForm').resetValidation();
      Session.set("editItemId", null);
    }
  }
});

Template._editItems.helpers({
  items: function() {
    return Items.find();
  },
});
```

```html
<template name="_editItems">
 <table class="ui very compact selectable celled table">
   <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>_id</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Service Name</th>
       <th>Service Id</th>
       <th>Edit</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     {{#each items}}
    {{> _editItemsItem}}
     {{/each}}
   </tbody>
 </table>
</template>

<template name="_editItemsItem">
 {{#if editing}} 
  <tr class="ui form">
   <td><div class="ui small input"><input type="text" id="editId" value="{{_id}}"></div></td>
   <td><div class="ui small input"><input type="text" id="editName" value="{{name}}"></div></td>
   <td><div class="ui small input"><input type="text" id="editServiceUsername" value="{{service.username}}"></div></td>
   <td><div class="ui small input"><input type="text" id="editServiceId" value="{{service.id}}"></div></td>
   <td>
    <button class="saveItem ui small circular primary button "><i class="ui save icon"></i></button>
    <button class="cancelItemEdit ui small circular red button "><i class="ui cancel icon"></i></button>
   </td>
  </tr>
 {{else}}
  <tr>
   <td>{{_id}}</td>
   <td>{{name}}</td>
   <td>{{service.username}}</td>
   <td>{{service.id}}</td>
   <td>
    <button class="editItem ui small circular button"><i class="ui edit icon"></i></button>
   </td>
  </tr>
 {{/if}}
</template>
```

Comment: Where you have `var editItem = {
    _id: $('#editId').val(),
    name: $('#editName').val(),
    "service.$.id": $('#editServiceId').val(), //not working
    "service.$.username": $('#editServiceUsername').val() //not working
  }` try instead `var editItem = {
    _id: $('#editId').val(),
    name: $('#editName').val(),
    service: { id: $('#editServiceId').val(), username: $('#editServiceUsername').val()}`
  }`

Comment: @MichelFloyd no luck with that unfortunately.  Anything else you think could work?

Comment: I excluded a few fields in the Item document that aren't getting updated.  Could that cause some sort of issue?

Comment: Well normally in your schema you would just have `services: { type: [subschema] }` and then define a subschema for services separately. What you might do is just start with `services: { type: [object] }` and see if you can define an array of subobjects without error. If your code is bombing when you create the `editItem` object then that's just a basic js problem in terms of creating an object correctly. Hard to tell without seeing the errors in your console.

Comment: Join me at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87922/pingo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got to the answer with the help of @MichelFloyd.

Schema should be as follows: (no $ signs)

```
 "service.$": {
    type: [Object]
  },
  "service.$.userid": {
    type: Number
  },
  "service.$.username": {
    type: String
  }
```

And then this will work:

```
 var editItem = {
   _id: $('#editId').val(),
   name: $('#editName').val(),
  "service.userid": $('#editServiceId').val(),
  "service.username": $('#editServiceUsername').val()
}
```